# How to convert all integer 64 columns in a dataframe to ints?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has integer 64 columns and I'd like to transfer them to regular ints.

I have trouble working with integer 64 because they behave in surprising ways

This is my code

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.integer64, as.numeric)
```

This is the error I'm getting: `Error in is_logical(.p) : object 'is.integer64' not found`

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(across(everything(),ifelse(is.integer(.),as.numeric(.),.)))`

Comment: I got this error: `Error in across(everything(), ifelse(is.integer(.), as.numeric(.), .)) : 
  could not find function "across"`

Comment: Load first `dplyr` (I hope you have the last version)

Comment: I loaded dplyr with the latest version and it gave me this error: `Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Can't convert a `factor` object to function
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(everything(), ifelse(is.integer(.), as.numeric(.), .))``

Comment: You have to omit the factor like `mutate(across(-myfactorvariable,ifelse(is.integer(.),as.numeric(.),.)))`

Comment: The issue is probably that you haven't loaded the `bit64` package.  `is.integer64()` is not a base function.